# How to call custom jquery function in phtml in magento 2.1

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, jquery, requirejs

I have some custom jquery functions and I want to create a common js files for all custom functions. But I am unable to find a way to achieve this.

I have created `requirejs-config.js` file at theme root(`app/desgin/frontend/Vendor/Theme/`). Content of `requirejs-config.js` file is:

```
var config = {
map: {
   '*': {
       'customfunctions' : 'js/customfunctions',
   }
},
paths: {
},};
```

Then I have created a `customfunctions.js` file which has custom functions. Path of file  is `app/desgin/frontend/Vendor/Theme/web/js`. Content of `customfunctions.js`  file is:

```
define(['jquery'], 
   function($) {
      function showDivtest() {
         alert("I am here");
      }
   };
```

Now, how I can call `showDivtest()` function in phtml file? Please suggest.

Comment: Do you want this by module?

Comment: @SohelRana What will be best option? I want to create separate files for custom jquery functions. So please suggest how I can register this file in all pages and call its function from any where. Or on some specific pages also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your custom script should change:

```
define(['jquery'],
 function($) {
    'use strict';
    return  {
        showDivtest: function () {
          alert("I am here");
        }
    }

});
```

Call via require Js in the template. For example, in your template:

```
<script> 
    require([
        'customfunctions'
    ], function (script) {
        script.showDivtest()
    });  
</script>
```

Comment: I tried this but it not working. Its throwing the error in console: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'showDivtest' of undefined`

Comment: @BalSingh see my updated answer. Remember to delete and run static content deploy again.

Comment: Yes its working. Can be call this function in html onclick event? like `<a href="javascript:void(0)"  onclick="script.showDivtest();"> `

Comment: You should create a jQuery Widget. Or, in your custom function `customfunctions.js`, you should return a function which includes the code for click event.